# Low Pass Filters in FPGA's

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I am trying to implement a Low Pass Filter in an FPGA using VHDL. Now, I worked out all the filter coefficients, but I am having trouble trying to understand how to work with the coefficients, given the fact that they are non-whole numbers. I would appreciate any help with an example of a simple filter implementation in VHDL.

Thanks a lot,
Chris

Comment: Using Stackoverflow search terms *[vhdl] low pass filter* reveals [VHDL truncation leads to malfunction of an implemented FIR Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416780/vhdl-truncation-leads-to-malfunction-of-an-implemented-fir-filter) which demonstrates the the fixed point method described by OldFart. Note the correction in the answer. The Y assignment shows using the best product to remove the fractional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the coefficients to fix-point numbers.

Very short:

- Chose a precision and multiply all coefficients by the nearest higher reciprocal power of two.
- Do the normal multiply-add operation in the FPGA.
- The end result should be divided by that same power of two.

Example:

- Coefficients are C0 = 0.707, C1= 0.123
- Lets take a precision of 0.5% which is 1/200
- Nearest power of 2 above 200 is 256
- C0 becomes 0.707*256 = 181, C1 becomes 0.123*256 = 31.
- Use those in your filter.
- At the end throw away the bottom 8 bits (As extra you can round using bit 7)

Comment: Still cannot make the filter work though, could you bekind enough as to show me a full implementation of a FIR filter, no need for a lot of coeffs, just 3 or 4 would be fine.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have a look into the VHDL 2008 fixed_pkg. It takes care of the power of two offsets for you. eg. `signal u6.3 : ufixed(5 downto -3);` so all calculations are done at the appropriate offsets. Positive index are 2^N, negative are 2^-N. It is the same integer arithmatic suggested by oldfart, but in a nicely wrapped coding style.

Comment: Tricky, but how can you install the fixed_pkg into the vhdl file ?