# How to get the square and cube of a fractional number (say 0.78) in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to Verilog/System Verilog and I wanted to implement the square and cube a fractional number. Consider the following example

```
module test(
  input wire [31:0] input, 
  output reg [63:0] output
);
reg [63:0] temp;
always @ (*) begin
          temp = input*input;
          output <= temp*input;
end
endmodule
```

So, when my `input` is **32'h0_C7AE147** (0.78 in the `hexadecimal` number system using the 32 bits representation and assuming `_` is the equivalent of `.` in Verilog) I expect an `output` of **32'h0_797C3D6** (0.4745 in `decimal` number system)

But I am getting an `output` of **64'hD546_4A9C_ED94_2917**

Also, how to handle the increasing bit sizes in a multiplication?

When we multiply *two* **N**-bit wide operands, we get an output of width **2N**-bits. When we multiply this *2N*-bit wide number with a *k* bit wide number, we get a number of widths *2N+k*-bit wide and this process goes on.

Comment: There are numerous ways of representing fractional numbers. Which one did you use (Or in other words:  can you explain how you got from 0.78 to 0xC7AE147?)

Comment: @Oldfart I didn't use any representations. I just used a decimal to the hexadecimal converter and kept the value of (0.78^3) in the decimal place. Accordingly, 0xC7AE147 is the output

Comment: *"I just used a decimal to the hexadecimal converter"* I am not aware of any decimal to the hexadecimal converter which can work with fractions unless it is one of the IEEE format. (I checked the IEEE 32-bit format of 0.78 and I did not get your number). You have probably done some weird number conversion and after multiplying the reverse conversion does not work.

Comment: @Oldfart It would be kind if you can please explain how to proceed further? Like how should I represent 0.78 and how to find it's cube?

Comment: The simplest is to use fixed point notation. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804713/low-pass-filters-in-fpgas/58805212#58805212) where I explain how to use fractions in an FIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to represent fractional number in 32-bit fixed point notation with 4-bit integer part + 28-bit fractional part?  And why do you need 64 bits for output?

Anyway I think you need to shift the product to the right by 28 bits for each multiplication.

Try:

```
temp = input * input >> 28;
output <= temp * input >> 28;
```

If you need proper rounding, do it before each shifting.

Comment: Suppose you need to represent a fractional number as a 3-digit decimal integer, say 0.78 as 078.
When squaring 078, you get 6084, but you need to right shift by 2 digits, because 0.78*0.78 = 0.6084 and its integer representation is 060.